# Azure Active Directory session_state

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure Active Directory to authenticate my users and this is the url that I redirect the users to:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2F&client_id=CB08A120-12BD-11E4-8143-DA6DD34483DE&scope=openid&response_mode=form_post&nonce=50b4146c-585c-49e5-a78e-56d9685c56f2
```

The response I get comes in the form of a post and has these two parameters:

```
id_token=*
session_state=*
```

However, I'm not exactly sure what `session_state` is. I've tried looking through the documentation, but can't seem to find a good answer. The places where I've found `session_state` in the documentation are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx) and [here](https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Authorization-Code-grant-in-AzureAD), but neither one helped very much. Is the `session_state` something I should be persisting in a cookie and sending to each future request to Azure? Or what is its purpose and the proper way to handle it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It identifies an authenticated session at the Azure AD STS.

After the first interactive sign-in, if you re-issue your OpenIDConnect SSO request, the user wont be prompted to sign-in again - yet your app will get back a fresh token, but the sessions_state will be the same as in the previous response. However in your SSO request if you add &prompt=login, the user will be prompted to login again, and this time the sessions_state you will get back will be different.

Most applications will just ignore the value - the ones that want to track that the user indeed re-authenticated will care.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When you say re-issue an OpenIDConnect SSO request, do you mean that they won't be prompted to sign in again if we pass the `session_state` along with the request?

Comment: No, it can be used to *detect* if a new session was created (by comparing last `session_request` with the current one). If nothing is passed, the user won't be re-prompted to sign in (assuming the cookie is still valid, etc.). If you pass `&prompt=login` to the request, you can force the user to re-authenticate.